# Why can't I define multiple variables to equal each other within an If statement?

Tags: c++

I am trying to set the different times to equal each other so that I can continue with the else if statement. But for some reason, it seems to not want to do it. Not only that, it seems to only recognize the first "TIE" that I have, even though it should be recognizing the other ones as well. What am I doing wrong?

```
if (time1 < time2 && time3)
{
    cout << "\nCongratualations " << racer1 << "!!! " << "You are the winner!!" << endl;
    cout << "\n***** Your winning time is: " << time1 << " *****" << endl;
}
else if (time2 < time1 && time3)
{
    cout << "\nCongratualations " << racer2 << "!!! " << "You are the winner!!" << endl;
    cout << "\n***** Your winning time is: " << time2 << " *****" << endl;
}
else if (time3 < time1 && time2)
{
    cout << "\nCongratualations " << racer3 << "!!! " << "You are the winner!!" << endl;
    cout << "\n***** Your winning time is: " << time3 << " *****" << endl;
}
else if ((time1 == time2) < time3)
{
    cout << "\nWe have a TIE " << racer1 << " and " << racer2 << " win!!" << endl;
    cout << "\n***** Your winning time is: " << time1 << " *****" << endl;
}
else if ((time2 == time3) < time1)
{
    cout << "\nWe have a TIE " << racer2 << " and " << racer3 << " win!!" << endl;
    cout << "\n***** Your winning time is: " << time2 << " *****" << endl;
}
else if ((time3 == time1) < time2)
{
    cout << "\nWe have a TIE " << racer1 << " and " << racer3 << " win!!" << endl;
    cout << "\n***** Your winning time is: " << time3 << " *****" << endl;
}
if (time1 == (time2 == time3))
{
    cout << "\nWe have a 3 way TIE!! No winner for this Race..." << endl;
    cout << "\n***** Your winning time is: " << time1 << " *****" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Please unsummon your Wall Of Code and replace it with a simplified example that contains only the code necessary to reproduce the issue.

Comment: It looks like you are writing code based on what you have *guessed* the syntax means to represent.  This will only get you into trouble.  It is worth going back to basics here to learn what each operator *actually* does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This: `(time1 < time2 && time3)` means `time1` is greater than `time2` and `time3` is true (non-zero).

What you probably meant was: `(time1 < time2 && time1 < time3)`

This: `(time1 == (time2 == time3))` means `time1` is equal to true (1) if `time2` is equal to `time3`, otherwise `time1` is equal to false (0).

What you probably meant was `(time1 == time2 && time1 == time3)`.

All of your other comparisons have similar problems.  Each binary comparison results in a simple bool.  You can't join up comparisons the way you do in speech.

Comment: Thanks md5i, you're a lifesaver, honestly. 

I appreciate the help as well from the comments, I'm taking c++ in college right now, so there is still much that I am not aware of.